# C++: Generating Preprocessed File in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, preprocessor

Building any c/c++ code generates `.exe` file. Is there any way that there will be another file generated for ex. `preprocessed.txt` which will contain preprocessed code? Anything that needs to be modified in tasks.json?

Here is the json file i normally use:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try adding "-E" to args

Comment: can't reproduce it on my machine unfortunately, but this could work

Comment: I tried it with "-E" args.  Gives error

Answer (score 0):

Add -E instead of -o it won't generate a .i file but it will produce the preprocessed code in the terminal..